# how to select all class elements of a page css with a condition

Tags: html, css

I want to select all the .turc (.box.turc) elements **if** a .turc element is hover
but i don't know how to do that:

```
<tr>
    <td class="box turc"></td>
    <td class="box gree"></td>
    <td class="box turc"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="box blue"></td>
    <td class="box turc"></td>
    <td class="box red"></td>
</tr>
```

I tried this but that's not ok ;( (here i select all the .turc in the .turc but that's not ok)

```
.box.turc:hover .turc
{
     -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
}
```

-

```
.box.turc:hover
```

do this:
[first try](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/684817Capturedcran20140401022007.png)
(i don't want ;()

The problem is to jump over all the tr section and select all the elements of the PAGE

And please I search this solution without jquery ;)
Thank you in advance !

Comment: just like this `.box.turc:hover {...}`

Comment: I am sorry but that doesn't work, i don't want this, i want all the turc of all the page ;(

Comment: You need `JS` for this, `CSS` won't be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have 'truc' in your HTML and 'turc' in your css.

Correct the spelling.

Then `.box.turc:hover` should be okay

Comment: I am sorry but that doesn't work, i don't want this, i want all the turc of all the page ;(

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, then you will need javascript.  The .box.turc:hover will only affect the currently hovered element.